# How to visualise projective points and hyperplanes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I am reading "Algebraic Geometry: A First Course" by Joe Harris and frankly I am very confused about projective $k$-planes, or maybe in general how points in projective space behave. I understand from the definition that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is simply defined as $K^{n+1}/\sim$ where $x\sim \lambda x$ for all $\lambda$, so is it normal to visualise a point in $\mathbb{P}^n$ as a line in $K^{n+1}$ passing through the origin?

Similarly, as the book proceeds to defining $k$-planes, it says

> An inclusion of vector spaces $W\cong K^{k+1}\to V\cong K^{n+1}$ induces a map $\mathbb{P}W\to \mathbb{P}V$; the image $\Lambda$ of such a map is called a *linear subspace of dimension $k$*, or *$k$-plane*, in $\mathbb{P}V$. In case $k=n-1$, we call $\Lambda$ a *hyperplane*. In case $k=1$ we all $\Lambda$ a *line*.

Intuitively, as points in $\mathbb{P}^n$ are lines through origin in $K^{n+1}$, is it safe to imagine a line in $\mathbb{P}^n$ as a two-dimensional plane through origin in $K^{n+1}$? And in general how do we handle with hyperplanes? For instance in Theorem 1.4 of the book, one of the sentence states

> if $\Gamma=\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$ is any decomposition of $\Gamma$ (a collection of $2n$ points in general position) into sets of cardinality $n$, then each $\Gamma_i$ will span a hyperplane $\Lambda_i\subset \mathbb{P}^n$.

Why is the last sentence true?

Sorry if this question seems a little bit vague. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are on the right track. A point in $\mathbb P^n$ indeed corresponds to a line in $K^{n+1}$ through $0$, although keep in might that these spaces do have concrete realizations. For instance over $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb P^1$ is the Riemann sphere. If you know some algebraic topology, its useful to compare the (co)homology of even-dimensional spheres with that of complex projective spaces to get a sense of how these two sequences of homogeneous spaces differ.

Comment: A hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n$ corresponds to a linear subpace of codimension $1$, i.e. a linear realization of $K^n \subset K^{n+1}$. For the theorem you cite, I believe the point is that any subset of a set of general points is itself general, and since two distinct points span a linear $\mathbb P^1$, three general points span a linear $\mathbb P^2$, etc., $n$ general points span a linear $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ which is a hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for the reply. So in particular, to see why two distinct points $x$ and $y$ span a linear line $\mathbb{P}^1$, is it because $ax+by$ in $K^{n+1}$ is a plane of dimension $2$? I'm still confused on whether I should treat $x$ and $y$ as points in a space or lines through $0$.

Comment: Again it's sometimes a matter of both. Two distinct points in $\mathbb P^n$ correspond to a pair of lines through $0$ in $K^{n+1}$, and those lines span a $2$-dimensional subspace (i.e. a plane that also contains $0$) which, looking back in $\mathbb P^n$, corresponds to a line down there. But the more comfortable you become with projective space, the more intuitive this correspondence will become.

Comment: @TabesBridges Hmm thanks, I guess that makes sense now.